# How to move my header-logo above the menu items?

Tags: html, css, mobile, header, shopify

I am trying to optimize my shopify store for mobile. But I ran in an issue that I can't fix. My mobile version looks like this right now: [image: see mobile version here]

I would like to make the logo bigger, but yet I need the other icons displayed aswell. I was wondering if there is a possibility to move the logo to a line above the other icons in mobile version. So my mobile header would have two lines; on the first is the logo and on the second all the other icons. This would look somehting like this: [image: see wish verison of mobile here]

My store url is: snow-pearl.com and I am using the debut shopify theme. You can find the `header.liquid` code by clicking [here.](https://gist.github.com/RemoZemp/acacc49d217ca974dd8405671bac838e)

If this isn't possible only for the mobile version, is it possible to implement in the desktop and mobile version? It doesn't matter if the logo is a line above everything else in the desktop version aswell.

Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

If you need to know anything more, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this CSS to make your block to switch to column.

```css
-webkit-flex-direction:column;
flex-direction: column;
```

[Flex-direction documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp)

On this existing CSS:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 749px){
  .site-header__mobile-nav{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    -o-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

After that you will need to fix the width of your blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can I ask another question: The Logo (grid) is now stuck on the left side and I would like to move it to the middle. But I can't just align it. Do I have to change a certain width oder do I have to align another class properly?

Comment: @Remo To do so, you have to remove your `padding-left` on your  `h1.h2.site-header__logo` by using the media query and then you can easily set `.logo-mobile.site-header__logo-image, .logo-mobile.site-header__logo-image img {margin:auto;} `

Comment: But this just slightly moves the logo to the right. So now it's not left-aligned but neither centered. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I dont see your modification so I cannot help if you dont provide a demo.

Comment: The mobile verison now looks like this: [image](https://i.ibb.co/YRJYH6V/mobile-2.png)

Comment: when I apply the code above on your live site it is working fine, so I dont know what you do wrong. Did you even check if the code is applied correctly ?

Comment: Can you show me how you applied the code? This way I might be able to spot the error that I have done.

Comment: It is in my 1st comment

Comment: Ah now it worked! Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.